how to import test files directly into another test file in playwright?
In my Playwright project. I tried to follow the POM (Page Object Model) framework. Here, I tried to separate my test suites and test cases. So, I created a folder called suites, and inside it, I want to import the googleLogin.spec.ts file.
The googleLogin.spec.ts file has two test cases written in it. But when I try to run the project, it gives the following error: "Error: test file 'suites\googleLoginTests.spec.ts' should not import test file 'testCases\googleLogin.spec.ts'."

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Error is pretty self-explanatory, though--don't import a test file from another test file. POMs are non-test files (no .test.js or .spec.js in the filename). POMs should not have test cases or test suites in them, just a class with locators and operations on those locators. Please read the docs.

Thanks for your response. Next time, I will remember about picture—thanks for enlightening me about that. Regarding the project, I had to follow a specific structure, which is why I was trying to import the test file into another test file. Good news is that the problem got solved, I had to make changes in the config file.

You are just not able to do so.
Never import any method form another file that contains ".spec".
Break the common methods into a util file and import them to the files that use them.
For example:
    export function setEntityName(entityName: string) {
        if (entityName == '' || entityName == undefined) {
            return 'test_' + generateRandomString(10)
        }
        return entityName
    }

This functions should be inside common-utils.ts file. Any time that you need to use this method - just import it.

hi, I had to modify config.ts file to make it work. btw thanks for your suggestion.
